# Custom UserControl breaks XAML Designerier and Intellisense

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a Windows Store Universal app and at the moment, I am focusing on WP8.1. I have created a custom UserControl, but whenever I include this custom control in a view using XAML, the XAML Designer fails to load the design view. It just sits displaying "Loading designer..." and using upwards of 60% CPU.

Normally I wouldn't be concerned with the Designer view because I prefer to modify the XAML directly. The problem is I lose intellisense when the designer is hung up which I rely on when writing XAML.

My example is of a Map Control that will work on both Windows Phone and Windows Store apps, but I have had this issue with other more simple controls as well.

Interestingly, the XAML Designer works fine when working on the UserControl directly. This is only an issue when including the UserControl in another view's XAML.

My UserControl XAML is:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyProject.Controls.MyMapControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyProject.Control"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="image" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the code behind looks like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;
#elif WINDOWS_METRO_APP
using Bing.Maps;
#endif

// The User Control item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234236

namespace MyProject.Controls
{
    public sealed partial class MyMapControl : UserControl
    {
        #if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
        private MapControl map;
        #elif WINDOWS_METRO_APP
        private Map map;
        private MapShapeLayer shapeLayer;
        #endif

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the MyMapControl with the appropriate credentials
        /// </summary>
        public MyMapControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            #if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
            map = new MapControl();
            map.MapServiceToken = "{map service token goes here}";
            #elif WINDOWS_METRO_APP
            map = new Map();
            map.Credentials = "{credentials go here"};
            shapeLayer = new MapShapeLayer();
            map.ShapeLayers.Add(shapeLayer);
            #endif
            this.main_grid.Children.Add(map);
        }

        #if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
        public double Pitch {
            get {
                return map.Pitch;
            }
            set {
                if(map.DesiredPitch != value) {
                    map.DesiredPitch = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Pitch");
                }
            }
        }

        public MapStyle Style {
            get {
                return map.Style;
            }
            set {
                if(value != map.Style) {
                    map.Style = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Style");
                }
            }
        }

        public MapColorScheme ColorScheme {
            get {
                return map.ColorScheme;
            }
            set {
                if(map.ColorScheme != value) {
                    map.ColorScheme = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ColorScheme");
                }
            }
        }

        private bool _ShowLocation = true;

        public bool ShowLocation {
            get {
                return this._ShowLocation;
            }
            set {
                if(this._ShowLocation != value) {
                    this._ShowLocation = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ShowLocation");
                }
            }
        }
        #endif

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set the map's ZoomLevel
        /// </summary>
        public double ZoomLevel {
            get {
                return map.ZoomLevel;
            }
            set {
                if(map.ZoomLevel != value) {
                    map.ZoomLevel = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ZoomLevel");
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set the map's manipulation mode
        /// </summary>
        public Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.ManipulationModes ManipulationMode {
            get {
                return map.ManipulationMode;
            }
            set {
                map.ManipulationMode = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set the map's center point
        /// </summary>
        public Geopoint Center {
            get {
                #if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
                return map.Center;
                #elif WINDOWS_METRO_APP
                return map.Center.ToGeopoint();
                #endif
            }
            set {
                #if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
                map.Center = value;
                #elif WINDOWS_METRO_APP
                map.Center = value.ToLocation();
                #endif
                OnPropertyChanged("Center");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set the map's credentials
        /// </summary>
        public string Credentials {
            get {
                #if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
                return map.MapServiceToken;
                #elif WINDOWS_METRO_APP
                return map.Credentials;
                #endif
            }
            set {
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
                    #if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
                    map.MapServiceToken = value;
                    #elif WINDOWS_METRO_APP
                    map.Credentials = value;
                    #endif
                    OnPropertyChanged("Credentials");
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set the map's display of traffic
        /// </summary>
        public bool ShowTraffic {
            get {
                #if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
                return map.TrafficFlowVisible;
                #elif WINDOWS_METRO_APP
                return map.ShowTraffic;
                #endif
            }
            set {
                #if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
                map.TrafficFlowVisible = value;
                #elif WINDOWS_METRO_APP
                map.ShowTraffic = value;
                #endif
                OnPropertyChanged("ShowTraffic");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set the current location for the map view as well as zoom level.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="center">BasicGeoposition for the center of the map view</param>
        /// <param name="zoom">Zoom Level at which to display map</param>
        public void SetView(BasicGeoposition center, double zoom) {
            #if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
            map.Center = new Geopoint(center);
            map.ZoomLevel = zoom;
            #elif WINDOWS_METRO_APP
            map.SetView(center.ToLocation(), zoom);
            #endif
            OnPropertyChanged("ZoomLevel");
            OnPropertyChanged("Center");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a basic push pin with text to the map at a specific location.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="location">Location for pushpin</param>
        /// <param name="text">Text to display with pushpin</param>
        public void AddPushpin(BasicGeoposition location, string text) {
            #if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
            Grid pin = new Grid() {
                Width = 34,
                Height = 24,
                Margin = new Thickness(-12)
            };
            pin.Children.Add(new Ellipse() {
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DodgerBlue),
                Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
                StrokeThickness = 3,
                Width = 24,
                Height = 24
            });
            pin.Children.Add(new TextBlock() {
                Text = text,
                FontSize = 12,
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
                HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Center
            });
            MapControl.SetLocation(pin, new Geopoint(location));
            map.Children.Add(pin);
            #elif WINDOWS_METRO_APP
            Pushpin pin = new Pushpin() {
                Text = text
            };
            MapLayer.SetPosition(pin, location.ToLocation());
            map.Children.Add(pin);
            #endif
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a polygon to the map
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="locations"></param>
        /// <param name="strokeColor"></param>
        /// <param name="strokeThickness"></param>
        public void AddPolygon(List<BasicGeoposition> locations, Color fillColor, Color strokeColor, double strokeThickness) {
            #if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
            MapPolygon line = new MapPolygon() {
                Path = new Geopath(locations),
                StrokeColor = strokeColor,
                StrokeThickness = strokeThickness
            };
            map.MapElements.Add(line);
            #elif WINDOWS_METRO_APP
            MapPolygon line = new MapPolygon() {
                Locations = locations.ToLocationCollection(),
                FillColor = fillColor
            };
            shapeLayer.Shapes.Add(line);
            #endif
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clears all elements on the map
        /// </summary>
        public void ClearMap() {
            #if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
            map.MapElements.Clear();
            #elif WINDOWS_METRO_APP
            shapeLayer.Shapes.Clear();
            #endif
            map.Children.Clear();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Notify Property Changed Event
        /// </summary>
        public event DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Notify Property Changed method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of modified property</param>
        internal void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried bypassing some code in the constructor if you're in design mode? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821718/avoid-xaml-designer-error-with-custom-controls

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out how to bypass code in the constructor based on whether I am in design mode or not, but when I comment out everything in the constructor except for this.InitializeComponent(), the problem persists.

Comment: It's probably the #if directives surrounding your private fields at the top.  The app platform would not likely be defined in design mode so it's choking on them.  I don't know of a workaround, though.

Comment: That's a good thought. I commented out the #if directives before and in the constructor. It didn't fix the problem though. Perhaps later when I have a little more time I will try removing all of them to see if that is the problem. It would kind of defeat the purpose of the control to remove them all, but if I could just figure out what is causing this, I would be able to figure out a way to live with it. Thanks Paul Abbott.

Comment: `DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)` can be used to check if you're in design mode.